# Differentiate the function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

$$v=\left(\sqrt{x} + {1\over x^{1\over 3}} \right)^2$$

We are working on differentiating functions. This one I have tried everything on and my teacher keeps saying I'm wrong. I'm just not seeing what i'm doing. Help?

Comment: If I read the thing right, you are looking at $(x^{1/2}+x^{-1/3})^2$. You could expand and differentiate term by term, or use the Chain Rule.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Knowing exponent rules, $v=(x^{1/2} + x^{-1/3})^2 = x + 2 \cdot x^{-1/6}+x^{-2/3}$

Hopefully you can take the power rule from there

Comment: Be careful. the middle term is 2*x^(-1/6)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the product rule: 
$$(u\cdot v)'=u'\cdot v+u\cdot v'$$
In the special case $v=u$, this reduces to:
$$(u^2)'=2\cdot u'\cdot u$$

This result could also have been obtained by chain rule [how?]. Now let, $u=x^{1/2}+x^{-1/3}$:
$$(u^2)'=2\cdot (x^{1/2}+x^{-1/3})'\cdot (x^{1/2}+x^{-1/3})$$

Can you go from here?